# How to install bg/freshdesk using composer on Magent 2.3

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

I am trying to install freshdesk (I am following this tutorial https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/223950-freshdesk-app-for-magento-2-0) but unfortunately the Module is not installed, both way using Composer and using copy folder.

**Using Composer**

[image]

**Without Composer (Copy Folder)**

[image]

**Module is not detected (Copy Folder)**

[image]

- my bad the folder structure should be  app/code/Bg/Freshdesk

Anyone can help about how to add freshdesk to the Magento 2.3 ?

Comment: for using Copy Folder it should be here: app/code/Bg/Freshdesk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no option to install Freshdesk using composer on Magento 2, you have to Copy the downloaded folder to the code folder.

Comment: yeah, I think you are right